# How to write a formula in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I write this formula for calculating principal and interest in T-SQL?

`(p*(r/n) / [1-(1+r) ^-(n)*(t)])`

Here is what I have already:

```
    set @result=(@princpleAmt*(@rate/@amortizedPayments)/(1-power(1+@rate,-@amortizedPayments))*@t)
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your formulation?  You seem to understand the SQL Server functions for this implementation.

Comment: What are then brackets (`[]`) representing here? Why do they differ from the parenthesis (`()`)?

Comment: I presume a missing reference to `FLOOR`

Comment: Probably `(1-power(1+@rate,-@amortizedPayments*@t))`

Comment: They can mean a few things (apparently): ([Square Bracket](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareBracket.html)). Although only a couple are likely applicable here, it does mean we don't know which it is.

Comment: the following link might help: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/downloads/